# How to display text translation in a new element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make script that will work like this: I have list of three words, and when  I move the mouse over them I need to get translated text in new element.

I created a list:

- Car
- Airplane
- Lion

And this function...

```
  <script>
  $(".word_split").lettering('car');
  $('.word_split').mouseover(function(event) {
  }
  </script>
```

So again, how to make script that will show me translated text in new element after I mouse over some of them.

Comment: Hello. Translated how? To a different language? Or did you just want the hover part.

Comment: Yeah, to different language, i can input translate and then just show it in new element when i put my mouse on an element from list.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54495181/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and show us a [mcve] of your efforts. For example what is `lettering`

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

I would store the translations in the HTML as attributes for a simple example like this.

Then using JQuery to:

1. first store the original word in another attribute
2. swap between the two attributes - the original and translated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.word_split').each(function(){
    var thisword = $(this);
    
    thisword.attr('data-original', thisword.text());
    
    thisword.mouseover(function(e){
      thisword.text(thisword.attr('data-translation'));
    })
    .mouseout(function(e){
      thisword.text(thisword.attr('data-original'));
    });
    
  });
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word_split" data-translation="Auto">Car</div>
<div class="word_split" data-translation="Letoun">Aeroplane</div>
<div class="word_split" data-translation="Lev">Lion</div>
```